# Error generating pdf with htmldoc framework

Tags: html, report, htmldoc

I am using htmldoc framework to generate pdf from html. When i try to generate the pdf report through my application i see the below error

**htmldoc[12087] general protection fault ip:561d4db9ecd8 sp:7ffd98a4d0c0 error:0 in htmldoc[561d4db8e000+36000]**

Then i tried to run the html doc command manually through terminal on the generated html file by the below command which internally my application uses

**htmldoc --quiet --bodyfont helvetica --header .t. --footer .1. --left 0.25in --size letter --fontsize 8 --format pdf --portrait --titlefile /var/sf/reports/temptitle0050568A-E781-0ed3-0000-008590044592.html --toctitle Table of Contents /var/sf/reports/temphtmlBody0050568A-E781-0ed3-0000-009373654931.html -f /var/sf/reports/0050568A-E781-0ed3-0000-008590044592.pdf**

I receive the below error this time
**Segmentation fault**

Currently i am using html doc **version 1.9.8** . Also i verified that the latest version is **1.9.18.**

So could anyone please help me is this a known bug with my html doc current version version 1.9.8. Also i verified the html content and don't find issue with the content of the html and the html size is not big.

Comment: Interesting part is when i edited the html file , basically deleted few random lines and added few more random line to increase the file size ,  the same command starts working. This proves that its not file size issue either.